# How to enable Android Studio to detect the missing JSON?

Tags: android-studio

Here it is SDK setup for my project in Android Studio. Now after I move the JSON file from file explorer to Android Studio and sync. I don't why Android Studio can't detect it within the app folder, and you can see that the icon is not a JSON file icon.

I have been stucked here for a long time.

[image: det]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution : the name must be "google-services.json" , "google-services(4).json" does not work.Then,rebulid the project,the error is solved.